# Represent a dictionary in a list of dictionaries as a number

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to provide a user with a choice as to how many (all, select few, single) list of dictionaries the script should run over.

Currently I can ask user to select based on key called "instance_name" but it is troublesome to type out the entire name. If user simply hit enter, it processes all. All dictionaries in the list have identical keys and structure.

```
data = r.json()
results = []
for i in data:
    print(i['instance_name'])
option = input("Please select instance to generate report. To generate for all, simply press [Enter]: ")
if len(option):
 for i in data:
    if option in i['instance_name']:
     results.append(
        (i['aps']['id'], i['instance_name'], i['login'], i['password']))
else:
 for i in data:
    results.append(
        (i['aps']['id'], i['instance_name'], i['login'], i['password']))
return results
```

Data looks like this:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(data[0])
{'aps': {'id': 'cd7f0e5f-dfad-41a8-ab99-52e7cbd75a94',
         'modified': '2017-05-27T07:26:45Z',
         'revision': 35,
         'status': 'aps:ready',
         'type': 'http://something/application/version'},
 'instance_name': 'Test1',
 'login': 'abcdd@xyz.com',
 'password': 'xxxxxx'}
>>> type(data)
<class 'list'>
>>> len(data)
17
>>>
```

Output currently is like this:

```
C:\Code>python -i options.py
Test1
Test2
...
Test17
Please select instance to generate report. To generate for all, simply press [Enter]: Test1
[('cd7f0e5f-dfad-41a8-ab99-52e7cbd75a94', 'Test1', 'abcdd@xyz.com', 'xxxxxx')]
>>>
```

Is there a way to represent these names alongside a number? So that the user can enter a number, or comma separated multiple numbers to select a single or multiple instance?

```
1. Test1
2. Test2
...
17. Test17
```

The list of dictionaries is not static, it can increase in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Use `enumerate`.

```
for i, dictionary in enumerate(dictionary_list):
    print(i, dictionary['instance_name']
```

Result:

```
1 Test1
2 Test2
3 Test3
...
```

Comment: This only addresses a relatively small part of the question. How would this tie into the code that identifies which option was selected?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach. First, create a map of the "index" to the dictionaries.

```
data = [
    {'instance_name': 'Test1', 'other': 'a'},
    {'instance_name': 'Test2', 'other': 'b'},
    {'instance_name': 'Test3', 'other': 'c'},
    {'instance_name': 'Test4', 'other': 'd'}
]

mapped_data = dict(enumerate(data, 1))
# { 1: {'instance_name': 'Test1', 'other': 'a'}, 
#   2: {'instance_name': 'Test2', 'other': 'b'}, 
#   3: {'instance_name': 'Test3', 'other': 'c'}, 
#   4: {'instance_name': 'Test4', 'other': 'd'}}
```

Then, write a function to look-up the dictionary given either the "index" or the value of `instance_name`.

```
def get_data(key, mapping, attr):
    k = key.strip()
    # find first member of mapping.items() whose index or d[attr] matches
    return next(d for i, d in mapping.items() if k == i or k == d[attr])

# binds mapped_data and 'instance_name' to the function
custom_get_data = lambda k: get_data(k, mapped_data, 'instance_name')
```

Finally, set up the prompt and input to reference these objects.

```
indices = range(1, len(data) + 1) # [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in indices:
    print('{}. {}'.format(i, mapped_data[i]['instance_name']))

option = input('Enter a value, nothing, or a comma separated list: ')

if not option:
    result_keys = indices

elif ',' in option:
    result_keys = option.split(',')

else:
    result_keys = [option]

results = map(custom_get_data, result_keys)
```

Comment: Please tell me if I understand this correctly: 
mapped_data is a dictionary with key "i" and value is instance_name, "i" is populate through enumerate i,d data so "i" would turn into the numbers and mapped to the names...? Sorry I am still learning

Comment: `mapped_data` is a dictionary with a key `i` and the value is an entire dictionary (including an `instance_name` key/value pair).